# Combine errorElement and custom error placement with jQuery.validate?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery.validate.js to validate a bunch of fields in my form. Because of some weird layout issues with IE6, I've set `errorElement: "div"` for the validator.

Unfortunately one of my fields has a custom label position using `<label for="type" class="error" generated="true"></label>` that's now broken.

Is there a way to fix the custom error placement? I've tried changing `label` to `div` with different combinations but none of it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out by inspecting the element with the chrome debugger. `for` needs to be changed to `htmlfor`. wtf.

```
<div htmlfor="type" class="error" generated="true"></div>
```